# Thumbnails not showing on network drive but on local drives. (Win 10 Pro)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, thumbnails

I just finished my new rig and installed Windows 10 Professional. I also have the latest version and all the updates.

When I go to my NAS, the explorer doesn't show thumbnails anymore (gif, png, jpg, etc). On my local drives, they are showing.

Here is what I tried already:

- Checked the settings and all is set to show thumbs and not icons.
- Deleted the thumbnails cache multiple times.
- Tried sagethumbs and icaros
- Created these registry entries:

  ```
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisableThumbnails Value 0
  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisableThumbnailsOnNetworkFolders Value 0
  ```
- Changed the folder content to pictures, but also no luck.

None of these worked. Does anyone have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed the issue. You have to add this reg key as well.

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisableThumbnailsOnNetworkFolders 0
```